# Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high : .Net 4.5

Tags: exception, .net-4.5

I'm getting an exception “System.InvalidOperationException: Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high.”

My application is developed in VS2010 with 4.0 framework and it is working fine in our development environment (4.0 version ) (for 4.0 framework I'm able to find the hotfix and I've installed it in my development environment). In production environment framework is upgraded to 4.5 version and we often getting the mentioned exception.

**Application developed** : windws 7 - 32 bit OS / vb.net 4.0
**Development environment** (hotfix installed) :  windows server 2008 - 64 bit  / dotnet FW 4.0
**Prod Environment** : windows server 2008 - 64 bit / dotnet FW 4.5

Kindly help me resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this? -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803755 . It seems to be for .NET 4.5. It says for WCF but might help in other scenarios I guess

Comment: @Jcl : I have read the artical, my os is windows server 2008  ,but in the prerequisites only windows 8 and  windows server 2012 are applicable  .

Comment: solution is available here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hot fix for 4.5 is available here : [kb2803754](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2803754)

And we need to contact the Microsoft support to get the hot fix installation file.
[MSDN thread for KB2803754 in .NET 4.5.1 framwork](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a3feddfd-ff21-438c-9704-661375f096af/is-that-the-hot-fix-kb2803754-included-in-net-framework-451-version-4550938?forum=clr#a3feddfd-ff21-438c-9704-661375f096af)